# I have to make changes in a logic where it fetches data from MySQL using certain conditions and I'm not sure how to do it?

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript

Okay so first

```
async getPRMsAvailability() {
  var prmsData = await getManager().query(
    'SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE prm.id, prm.firstName, prm.lastName, COUNT(student.id) as students FROM prm LEFT JOIN student ON prm.id = student.prm_id group by prm.id order by count(student.id) asc limit 1'
  );

  return prmsData;
}
```

This is the code that is already present in my file what this code does is from the `prm` table it takes `id`, `firstname`, `lastname` and assigns it to the total count of student ids present in student table the only change I want here is that it should also consider the status column from the student table and only consider it for those students whose `status(student.status)` is active and not all students.

Comment: Add, WHERE student.status = 'active status'

Comment: but where exactly should I add it

Comment: You should spend some time researching sql where clause.

Comment: Before group by and read this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html